# Problem with executing alias of a command on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, alias

I created an alias file for holding alias

```
nano .bash_aliases
```

and then used the command

```
alias ganache='./ganachescript'
```

However,

```
$ ./ganachescript

08:29:17.571 › Checking for update
08:29:19.052 › Update for version 2.4.0 is not available (latest version: 2.4.0, downgrade is disallowed).
```

but if I write:

```
$ ganache
ganache: command not found
```

Somebody please guide me.

Comment: have you sourced the file *source .bash_aliases*

Comment: @bac0n Would you like to post an answer?

Answer (score 2):

That's a quite not-correct way to set an alias. The command `./ganachescript` means '*execute the executable file* `ganachescript` *that exists in the **current** directory*'. So the alias would work *only* when you run the `ganache` command in the specific directory where the `ganachescript` file is located.

To overcome this you need to use the full path to the `ganachescript` file instead as below

```
alias ganache='/path/to/ganachescript'
```

Comment: I tried with 'source' command and it worked.

Comment: Yes, you may need to source it so that it starts working immediately. But as the answer explains, it's not a wise idea to use the `./ganachescript` command for the alias. Try it yourself, first change your current working directory to a different one with the `cd` command, and then run the `ganache` command. You'll again get a `command not found` error (provided you used the `./ganachescript` command for the alias).